# Characterizing rank along "lower envelope" of points

Tags: kernel-smoothing, spearman-rho

Suppose I have data that looks like this.

[image]

I want to quantify how well the "lower envelope" of the points are described by a monotonic function. The measure will be used to compare sets of points and should prefer sets with more closely monotonic lower envelopes. Emphasis should be placed on individual outliers of low y and high x that break from monotonicity (red points).

By "lower envelope" I roughly mean the points circled in yellow.

[image: lower envelope]

How can I turn what I want to characterize into a number?

**My thoughts on how I might do this:**

For defining the lower envelope of the points, I could use conditional kernel density estimation. The lower envelope would then be defined as some bottom % of y for given x.

Following this procedure I could then either characterize the points that are within that % cutoff or characterize the density distribution itself.

Characterizing the points seems straightforward. I was thinking of Spearman's rho. This approach has the advantage of being simple however the data is such that some regions of x values may be heavily sampled and others may be more sparse. I'm not sure if that would cause a problem.

Characterizing the conditional density estimate might be preferable but I have no idea how to get a sense of rank in y given density estimates along x. One way would be to pick a % y for the conditional density estimate along x and calculate rank from points along x at that % y. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Have you looked at quantile regression and the possibility of comparing the fit of monotonic linear or non-linear vs. broken stick regression for instance ? Just my two cents...